# Adjusting (Stacked) Bar Width according to Proportions of Categories in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, width, bar-chart

I'm trying to change my (stacked) bar width according to the counts (or proportion) of the categories, As an example i used the diamonds dataset. I want to see a varying width according to the frequency of each category (of the variable `cut`). I first created a variable `cut_prop` and then plotted with the following code

```
library(tidyverse)

cut_prop = diamonds %>% 
  group_by(cut) %>% 
  summarise(cut_prop = n()/nrow(diamonds))

diamonds = left_join(diamonds, cut_prop)

ggplot(data = diamonds, 
       aes(x = cut, fill = color)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(width=cut_prop), position = "fill") + 
  theme_minimal() +
  coord_flip()
```

Which gave me the following barplot:

[image]

R gives a warning which tells: `Ignoring unknown aesthetics: width` and obviously doesn't take the proportion of categories for the width of the bars into account, anyone who can help me out here? Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean like a mosaic plot? I've used the [`ggmosaic` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggmosaic/vignettes/ggmosaic.html) for this. I've also seen [this tutorial](https://learnr.wordpress.com/2009/03/29/ggplot2_marimekko_mosaic_chart/) for doing it with `geom_rect`s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this works. Starting where you left off...

```
df <- diamonds %>% 
  count(cut, color, cut_prop) %>% 
  group_by(cut) %>% 
  mutate(freq = n / sum(n)) %>% 
  ungroup

ggplot(data = df,
       aes(x = cut, fill = color, y = freq, width = cut_prop)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  theme_minimal() +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Essentially, I calculate the proportions myself instead of using `position = "fill"`, then use `stat = identity` rather than `stat = count`.